# Beeline command to extract in fixed width .dat format

Tags: hadoop, hive, extract, fixed-width, beeline

I have a hive/hadoop table loaded as below with 3 columns, name (10 bytes), age (3 bytes) and marks (5 bytes).

[image]

What could be the beeline command to extract this data into a fixed width .dat file as below ? or is there ay other way to achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest SparkSQL over beeline, but why fixed width compared to csv?

Comment: We are replacing one of the on-prem processes that takes in fixed width file and outputs fixed width after a character level encryption. So it's required that we output fixed width. Can you please share how to extract with SparkSQL query (if not possible with beeline) ?